# What is the usual temperature in an airplane?

Tags: air-travel, factoids, aircraft

What degree is the temperature set to in an international airplane ?

I am not looking for answers to adjust the fan speed directly on top of my head. I am more interested in knowing the temperature in a typical international flight (if it matters, from Darwin, Australia to Singapore in a Silk airways flight). I need to be prepared to take my infant (less than 2 years of age) in a airline provided bassinet who is accustomed to a certain temperature in daily routines.

Comment: I would assume "room temperature" but they do seem to set it cooler at "night time" ie "when the blinds are shut".

Comment: @pnuts: Interesting how we sometimes need the airline blanket at "night time" but not the rest of the time.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the airline, and the geographic area.

For example, transatlantic Delta flights are quite cold (typically around 20C/70F, could be 18C). I've been on like 50 of them, and they all were like that.

However all transatlantic flights I've been on on Lufthansa (only 6 or 8 though) were all uncomfortably warm (25C), and the staff said "we always keep it like that".

Now, Delta flights between Tokyo and Shanghai, or Tokyo and Manila are warm. Probably around the same 25C as Lufthansa ones.